# Export SPGridView to Excel tabs

Tags: excel, spgridview

I have multiple SPGridViews on a page.  I would like to export them all to one Excel document, each SPGridView on its own tab.  Is this possible?

[This link](http://www.fivenumber.com/export-spgridview-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-2007/) is a great start but does not solve my tab issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go the [OpenXML route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom export logic by using the COM Interop libraries. The class is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. You probably have to download the MSO Interop pack unless you already have it. Just make sure to get the right Interop libraries for the version of Excel you're targeting.

Tabs are Worksheet objects. The Excel document is the Workbook object.

Here's the link to the class library on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  However I would love to avoid completely rewriting this solution if possible.

Comment: Well, let me know if you figure it out a different way, or just post it as an answer.